# Prolog List of Constants to String

Tags: string, list, prolog

i have a list in input: [asd,qweqwe,fsdf,lkasd]
As un can see from the code i want connect each constant of the list to output a single variable list.
i m using yap prolog, i consult this code and i write :- run.
the write function print out _G1233 and not 'asd,asd2,asd3,asd4'
why ? how i have to change the code for output me 'asd,asd2,asd3,asd4' ?

```
run :- toAtomicVars([asd,asd2,asd3,asd4],',',Out),
write(Out),nl.


toAtomicVars([],In,Out).
toAtomicVars([A|B],In,Out) :-
atomic_concat(A,In,Out1),
atomic_concat(',',Out1,Out2),
toAtomicVars(B,Out2,Out2).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you (should) get a warning like

```
Singleton variables: [In,Out]
Singleton variables: [Out]
```

that means that you dont really do anything with those variables:

```
toAtomicVars([],In,Out).
```

In and Out can be anything, so prolog just prints a dummy value, _Gsomething that means that the variable is not instantiated.

same thing happens in the second clause:

```
toAtomicVars([A|B],In,Out) :-
  atomic_concat(A,In,Out1),
  atomic_concat(',',Out1,Out2),
  toAtomicVars(B,Out2,Out2).
```

you dont say anywhere what is that Out.

personally i think that it would be easier if you just printed each variable recursively and then print a comma, something like:

```
print_list([X]):-
  write(X).
print_list([H|T]):-
   write(H),
   write(', '),
   print_list(T).
```

but if you want to put commas in the list you should add a rule that defines Out.

Comment: toAtomicVars([A|B],InOut) :-
  atomic_concat(A,InOut,Out),
  atomic_concat(',',Out,Out2),
  toAtomicVars(B,Out2).   what do you think about this?

Comment: try something like toAtomicVars([A|B],Out):- atomic_concat(A,',',O1), toAtomicVars(B,O2), atomic_concat(O1,O2,O).
if you call toAtomicVars([a,b,c,d],Out), O1 will be 'a,', O2 will be 'b,c,d' and then you will concat them and get 'a,b,c,d'